# As a Syrian, will I need a transit visa for Stockholm Arlanda airport?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, stockholm, syrian-citizens

I am a Syrian citizen. In a month’s time I am going to China, transitioning in Istanbul from Beirut.

My return ticket is from China to Istanbul, transitioning in Stockholm Arlanda.

Will I need a transit visa for Stockholm?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Facts about entry visas](http://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Visiting-Sweden/Facts-about-visas.html), citizens of Syria do need a visa to transit in Sweden. The list of countries is at the bottom of the page under "Countries whose citizens require a visa".